# How to retrieve specific element (or nodelist) within an existing element from DOM in Java

Tags: java, dom

I am trying to parse an XML file which contains multiple records of name `A`. Each `A` has multiple group records with name `B` . The various records within `B` have names `x`, `y` and `z`.

My questions are:

- How do I navigate to `B` and
- how do I obtain all values of `x` in loop.

The DOM is set to the document (i.e. elements of name "A")

I am using a DOM parser in Java.

Sample record:

```
<A>
  <B><x>123</x><y>asdf</y><z>A345</z></B>
  <B><x>987</x><y>ytre</y><z>Z959</z></B>
</A>
```

Comment: I'm bit confused about XML structure you described in above post. Please post the document fragment.

Comment: @AVD I have added a sample xml record...

Answer (score 0):

```
    Document yourDom = ....;

    XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xp = xpf.newXPath();

    XPathExpression xpe = xp.compile("//A/B/*");
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpe.evaluate(yourDom, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Comment: hi... is there any rule for the number of slashes before A and after B? kindly explain that (with the help of the example for A->B->x...

Comment: two slashes means, find A anywhere in the document. one slash means find the Bs as a direct child of A. As you didn't specify exactly your requirements i did it this way.

Comment: if A is the root of the document you can use `/A/B/*`

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using the standard DOM API directly which is usually a bit verbose for these tasks, you could also use [jOOX](http://code.google.com/p/joox/) as a [jquery](http://jquery.org)-like wrapper for DOM. Here's an example how to use it:

```
// Loop over all x element values within B using css-style selectors
for (String x : $(document).find("B x").texts()) {
  // ...
}

// Loop over all x element values within B using XPath
for (String x : $(document).xpath("//B/x").texts()) {
  // ...
}

// Loop over all x element values within B using the jOOX API
for (String x : $(document).find("B").children("x").texts()) {
  // ...
}
```